# Nav menu will not close when clicking the button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have attempted to follow a guide for a scroll reveal website, however i keep running into the issue where my nav menu will not close, it constantly shows, however the code i copied over is the exact same as in the video/documentation. The idea is that when i click a javascript made button it should close my nav then open it.

Would appreciate some help

```js
/*=============== SHOW MENU ===============*/
const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu'),
      navToggle = document.getElementById('nav-toggle'),
      navClose = document.getElementById('nav-close')

/*===== MENU SHOW =====*/
/* Validate if constant exists */
if(navToggle){
    navToggle.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        navMenu.classList.add('show-menu')
    })
}

/*===== MENU HIDDEN =====*/
/* Validate if constant exists */
if(navClose){
    navClose.addEventListener('click', () =>{
        navMenu.classList.remove('show-menu')
    })
}

/*=============== REMOVE MENU MOBILE ===============*/
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')

const linkAction = () =>{
    const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu')
    // When we click on each nav__link, we remove the show-menu class
    navMenu.classList.remove('show-menu')
}
navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener('click', linkAction))

/*=============== CHANGE BACKGROUND HEADER ===============*/
const scrollHeader = () =>{
    const header = document.getElementById('header')
    // When the scroll is greater than 50 viewport height, add the scroll-header class to the header tag
    this.scrollY >= 50 ? header.classList.add('bg-header') 
                       : header.classList.remove('bg-header')
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHeader)

/*=============== SHOW SCROLL UP ===============*/ 


/*=============== SCROLL SECTIONS ACTIVE LINK ===============*/


/*=============== DARK LIGHT THEME ===============*/ 


/*=============== SCROLL REVEAL ANIMATION ===============*/
```

```css
/*=============== GOOGLE FONTS ===============*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@600&family=Lora:wght@500;600&family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap");

/*=============== VARIABLES CSS ===============*/
:root {
  --header-height: 3.5rem;

  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  /*Color mode HSL(hue, saturation, lightness)*/
  --first-color: hsl(19, 64%, 54%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(19, 64%, 52%);
  --title-color: hsl(19, 16%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(19, 16%, 35%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(19, 8%, 55%);
  --body-color: hsl(19, 100%, 96%);
  --container-color: hsl(19, 100%, 97%);

  /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
  /*.5rem = 8px | 1rem = 16px ...*/
  --body-font: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  --title-font: "Lora", serif;
  --subtitle-font: "Dancing Script", cursive;
  --biggest-font-size: 2.25rem;
  --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  --small-font-size: .813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: .75rem;

  /*========== Font weight ==========*/
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;

  /*========== z index ==========*/
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  :root {
    --biggest-font-size: 4rem;
    --h1-font-size: 2.25rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.5rem;
    --h3-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --small-font-size: .875rem;
    --smaller-font-size: .813rem;
  }
}

/*=============== BASE ===============*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  transition: background 0.4s; /* for dark mode animation */
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*=============== THEME ===============*/


/*========== Variables Dark theme ==========*/


/*========== 
    Color changes in some parts of 
    the website, in light theme
==========*/


/*=============== REUSABLE CSS CLASSES ===============*/
.container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-inline: 1.5rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.section {
  padding-block: 5rem 1rem;
}

.section__title {
  font-size: var(--h1-font-size);
  font-family: var(--title-font);
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.section__subtitle {
  display: block;
  font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
  font-family: var(--subtitle-font);
  color: var(--first-color);
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.section__title, 
.section__subtitle {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  overflow: hidden; /* For animation ScrollReveal */
}

/*=============== HEADER & NAV ===============*/
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  transition: box-shadow .3s, background .4s;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__logo,
.nav__toggle,
.nav__close{
  display: flex;
  color: var(--title-color);
}

.nav__logo{
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .5rem;
  font-family: var(--title-font);
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
  transition: color .3s;
}

.nav__logo img{
  width: 25px;
}

.nav__logo:hover{
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__toggle{
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .nav__menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 20px hsla(19, 64%, 24%, .1);
    padding-block: 3.5rem;
    transition: top .4s;
  }
}

.nav__list{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  row-gap: 2rem;
}

.nav__link{
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  transition: color .4s;
}

.nav__link:hover{
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__img-1,
.nav__img-2{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .2;
}

.nav__img-1{
  width: 100px;
  top: .75rem;
  left: -2rem;
  transform: rotate(165deg);
}

.nav__img-2{
  width: 50px;
  right: -1rem;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.
/* Show menu */
.show-menu{
  top: 0;
}

/* Change background header */
.bg-header{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px hsla(19, 64%, 24%, .1);
}

/* Active link */


/*=============== HOME ===============*/
.home{
  position: relative;
}

.home__container{
  row-gap: 3rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.home__img{
  width: 300px;
  justify-self: center;
}

.home__data{
  text-align: center;
}

.home__title{
  font-size: var(--biggest-font-size);
  font-family: var(--title-font);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.home__title img{
  width: 40px;
}

.home__title div{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.home__description{
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.home__leaf-1,
.home__leaf-2{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .2;
}

.home__leaf-1{
  width: 80px;
  top: 8rem;
  left: -1rem;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.home__leaf-2{
  width: 100px;
  right: -2rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

/*=============== BUTTON ===============*/
.button{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .5rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  transition: background .3s;
}

.button i{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.button:hover{
  background-color: var(--first-color-alt);
}

.button:hover i{
  transform: translateX(.25rem);
}

/*=============== ABOUT ===============*/
.about{
  position: relative;
}

.about__container{
  row-gap: 3rem;
}

.about__data{
  text-align: center;
}

.about__title img{
  width: 30px;
}

.about__title div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.about__img{
  width: 300px;
  justify-self: center;
}

.about__leaf{
  width: 100px;
  opacity: .2;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1.5rem;
  bottom: 11rem;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

/*=============== POPULAR ===============*/
.popular__container{
  padding-top: 4rem;
  grid-template-columns: 250px;
  justify-content: center;
  row-gap: 5.5rem;
}

.popular__card{
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  padding: 7rem 2rem 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px hsla(19, 64%, 48%, .08);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.popular__img{
  width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  top: -2.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: transform .4s;
}

.popular__name{
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  font-family: var(--title-font);
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.popular__description{
  display: block;
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.popular__price{
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.popular__button{
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px hsla(19, 64%, 20%, .2);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.25rem;
  right: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .3s;
}

.popular__button:hover{
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.popular__card:hover .popular__img{
  transform: translateY(-.25rem);
}

/*=============== RECENTLY ===============*/


/*=============== NEWSLETTER ===============*/


/*=============== FOOTER ===============*/


/*=============== SCROLL BAR ===============*/


/*=============== SCROLL UP ===============*/


/* Show Scroll Up*/


/*=============== BREAKPOINTS ===============*/
/* For small devices */


/* For medium devices */


/* For large devices */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <!--=============== FAVICON ===============-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/favicon.png">

        <!--=============== REMIXICONS ===============-->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--=============== CSS ===============-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css">

        <title>Kaas</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--==================== HEADER ====================-->
        <header class="header" id="header">
            <nav class="navcontainer">
                <a href="#" class="nav__logo">
                    <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo image">
                    Kaas
                </a>

                <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="nav__list">
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#home" class="nav__link">Home</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#about" class="nav__link">About us</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#popular" class="nav__link">Popular</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#recently" class="nav__link">Recently</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Close button -->
                    <div class="nav__close" id="nav-close">
                        <i class="ri-close-line"></i>
                    </div>

                    <img src="assets/nav__img-1.png" alt="nav iamge" class="nav__img-1">
                    <img src="assets/nav__img-2.png" alt="nav iamge" class="nav__img-2">
                </div>

                <div class="nav__buttons">
                    <!-- Theme change button -->
                    <!-- <i class="ri-moon-line change-theme" id="theme-button"></i> -->

                    <!-- Toggle button -->
                    <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
                        <i class="ri-apps-2-line"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!--==================== MAIN ====================-->
        <main class="main">
            <!--==================== HOME ====================-->
            <section class="home section" id="home">
                <div class="home__container container grid">
                    <img src="assets/home-1.png" alt="home image" class="home__img">

                    <div class="home__data">
                        <h1 class="home__title">
                            Geniet van

                            <div>
                               <img src="assets/home-2.png" alt="home image">
                               Goeie Kaas
                            </div>
                        </h1>

                        <p class="home__description">
                            Geniet van lekkere kaas met je hele familie
                            Of gewoon alleen.
                        </p>

                        <a href="#" class="button">
                            Bestel Hier <i class="ri-arrow-right-line"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <img src="assets/home-leaf-1" alt="home image" class="home__leaf-1">
                <img src="assets/home-leaf-2" alt="home image" class="home__leaf-2">
            </section>

            <!--==================== ABOUT ====================-->
            <section class="about section" id="about">
                <div class="about__container container grid">
                    <div class="about__data">
                        <span class="section__subtitle">About Us</span>
                        <h2 class="section__title about__title">
                            <div>
                                Wij Bieden U
                                <img src="assets/about-kaas-title.png" alt="about image">
                            </div>

                            Goede kaas
                        </h2>

                        <p class="about__description">
                            Kaas die van de echte kaasboer komt,
                            beter dan de kaas van de supermarkt,
                            beter dan dit kan het niet.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <img src="assets/about-kaas" alt="about image" class="about__img">
                </div>

                <img src="assets/home-leaf-1" alt="about image" class="about__leaf">
            </section>

            <!--==================== POPULAR ====================-->
            <section class="popular section" id="popular">
                <span class="secton__subtitle">De Beste Kaas</span>
                <h2 class="section__title">Populaire Kaas</h2>

                <div class="popular__container container grid">
                    <article class="popular__card">
                        <img src="assets/popular-kaas-1" alt="popular image" class="popular__img">

                        <h3 class="popular__name">Kaas 1</h3>
                        <span class="popular__description">Kaas 1</span>

                        <span class="popular__price">€5,00-</span>

                        <button class="popular__button">
                            <i class="ri-shopping-bag-line"></i>
                        </button>
                    </article>

                    <article class="popular__card">
                        <img src="assets/popular-kaas-2" alt="popular image" class="popular__img">

                        <h3 class="popular__name">Kaas 2</h3>
                        <span class="popular__description">Kaas 2</span>

                        <span class="popular__price">€5,00-</span>

                        <button class="popular__button">
                            <i class="ri-shopping-bag-line"></i>
                        </button>
                    </article>

                    <article class="popular__card">
                        <img src="assets/popular-kaas-3" alt="popular image" class="popular__img">

                        <h3 class="popular__name">Kaas 3</h3>
                        <span class="popular__description">Kaas 3</span>

                        <span class="popular__price">€5,00-</span>

                        <button class="popular__button">
                            <i class="ri-shopping-bag-line"></i>
                        </button>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!--==================== RECENTLY ====================-->
            <section class="recently section" id="recently">
                <div class="recently__container container grid">
                    <div class="recently__data">
                        <span class="section__subtitle">Recent toegevoegd</span>
                        <h2 class="section__title">
                            Kaas 1 <br>
                            Kaas 2
                        </h2>

                        <p class="recently__description">
                            Bekijk hier de nieuwe producten.
                        </p>

                        <a href="#" class="button">
                            Bestel Hier <i class="ri-arrow-right-line"></i>
                        </a>

                        <img src="assets/recently.png" alt="recently image" class="rcenlt__data-img">
                    </div>

                    <img src="assets/recently-2.png" alt="recently image" class="recently__img">
                </div>
            </section>

            <!--==================== NEWSLETTER ====================-->
            <section class="newsletter section">
                
            </section>
        </main>

        <!--==================== FOOTER ====================-->
        <footer class="footer">
            
        </footer>

        <!--========== SCROLL UP ==========-->


        <!--=============== SCROLLREVEAL ===============-->
        <script src=""></script>

        <!--=============== MAIN JS ===============-->
        <script src="assets/main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

it appears that for some reason the close button will not close the menu
it is constantly displaying for me and i truly don't understand why.
in the video i watched it simply removes the close menu when clicking the X
and when u click the 4 dots it should open the menu.
It also appears that the 4 dots are stuck in the bottom left of the nav menu in stead of being in the top right where they're meant to be.
Would greatly appreciate some help.

As per request i have inserted the full html/css/javascript into the post. Do keep in mind the project is not fully finished yet

Comment: Can you attach full html code?

Comment: Kindly try to attach a working example not just a tiny part.

Comment: I've fully added all the code up to this point, though it is not fully finished yet.

Comment: There can be any number of reasons why your button is not behaving as you expect it to (the visual effect) The Javascript part is correct - by clicking on the X button, the class `.show-menu` is actually removed from the `#nav-menu` element. However, that is not enough to hide it. Are you sure you haven't missed a step in the tutorial you're following? There are ways to fix this, but they might involve deviating from the route your tutorial is setting for you. Do you want me to post a solution for your problem? I'll explain the steps.

Comment: I'll also add a link to the tutorial i followed for said template, i truly didn't deviate to these steps https://youtu.be/HW1zt2EPMqY?t=1125 the part where he adds the buttons to hide the nav menu is around that timestamp, so far i do appreciate all the help i've been getting so thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does work. Take a look into your CSS and you'll see that you're using a Media Query in which you're positioning the `.nav__menu` outside of the screen. The Media Query has a `max-width: 767px;`, so on everything wider than that, the CSS won't get applied. If you start to resize your screen, you'll see that eventually the hamburger menu will disappear and works just fine when clicking on the button!

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .nav__menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 20px hsla(19, 64%, 24%, .1);
    padding-block: 3.5rem;
    transition: top .4s;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add toggle function in js. Also, I changed some css code

```js
/*=============== SHOW MENU ===============*/
const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu'),
      navToggle = document.getElementById('nav-toggle'),
      navClose = document.getElementById('nav-close');

/*===== MENU SHOW =====*/
/* Validate if constant exists */
if(navToggle){
    navToggle.addEventListener('click', () =>{
         const navs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__list')
  
  navs.forEach(nav => nav.classList.toggle('Navbar__ToggleShow'));
      // const closeMenu = document.getElementById("nav-close");
      // closeMenu.classList.toggle("nav-close")

    })
}

/*===== MENU HIDDEN =====*/
/* Validate if constant exists */
if(navClose){
    navClose.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      const navs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__list')
      navs.forEach(nav => nav.classList.remove("Navbar__ToggleShow"));
        
    })
}

/*=============== REMOVE MENU MOBILE ===============*/
const navLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__link')

const linkAction = () =>{
    const navMenu = document.getElementById('nav-menu')
    // When we click on each nav__link, we remove the show-menu class
    navMenu.classList.remove('show-menu')
}
navLink.forEach(n => n.addEventListener('click', linkAction))

/*=============== CHANGE BACKGROUND HEADER ===============*/
const scrollHeader = () =>{
    const header = document.getElementById('header')
    // When the scroll is greater than 50 viewport height, add the scroll-header class to the header tag
    this.scrollY >= 50 ? header.classList.add('bg-header') 
                       : header.classList.remove('bg-header')
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHeader)

/*=============== SHOW SCROLL UP ===============*/ 


/*=============== SCROLL SECTIONS ACTIVE LINK ===============*/


/*=============== DARK LIGHT THEME ===============*/ 


/*=============== SCROLL REVEAL ANIMATION ===============*/
```

```css
/*=============== GOOGLE FONTS ===============*/
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@600&family=Lora:wght@500;600&family=Poppins:wght@400;500&display=swap");

/*=============== VARIABLES CSS ===============*/
:root {
  --header-height: 3.5rem;

  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  /*Color mode HSL(hue, saturation, lightness)*/
  --first-color: hsl(19, 64%, 54%);
  --first-color-alt: hsl(19, 64%, 52%);
  --title-color: hsl(19, 16%, 15%);
  --text-color: hsl(19, 16%, 35%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(19, 8%, 55%);
  --body-color: hsl(19, 100%, 96%);
  --container-color: hsl(19, 100%, 97%);

  /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
  /*.5rem = 8px | 1rem = 16px ...*/
  --body-font: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  --title-font: "Lora", serif;
  --subtitle-font: "Dancing Script", cursive;
  --biggest-font-size: 2.25rem;
  --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  --small-font-size: .813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: .75rem;

  /*========== Font weight ==========*/
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;

  /*========== z index ==========*/
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  :root {
    --biggest-font-size: 4rem;
    --h1-font-size: 2.25rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.5rem;
    --h3-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --small-font-size: .875rem;
    --smaller-font-size: .813rem;
  }
}

/*=============== BASE ===============*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
  transition: background 0.4s; /* for dark mode animation */
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/*=============== THEME ===============*/


/*========== Variables Dark theme ==========*/


/*========== 
    Color changes in some parts of 
    the website, in light theme
==========*/


/*=============== REUSABLE CSS CLASSES ===============*/
.container {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin-inline: 1.5rem;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.section {
  padding-block: 5rem 1rem;
}

.section__title {
  font-size: var(--h1-font-size);
  font-family: var(--title-font);
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.section__subtitle {
  display: block;
  font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
  font-family: var(--subtitle-font);
  color: var(--first-color);
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.section__title, 
.section__subtitle {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  overflow: hidden; /* For animation ScrollReveal */
}

/*=============== HEADER & NAV ===============*/
.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  transition: box-shadow .3s, background .4s;
}

.nav {
  position: relative;
  height: var(--header-height);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav__logo,
.nav__toggle,
.nav__close{
  display: flex;
  color: var(--title-color);
}


.nav__logo{
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .5rem;
  font-family: var(--title-font);
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
  transition: color .3s;
}

.nav__logo img{
  width: 25px;
}

.nav__logo:hover{
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__toggle{
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px){
  .nav__menu{
    position: fixed;
    top: -100%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--body-color);
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 20px hsla(19, 64%, 24%, .1);
    padding-block: 3.5rem;
    transition: top .4s;
  }
}

.nav__list{
  display:none;
}

.nav__link{
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  transition: color .4s;
}

.nav__link:hover{
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav__img-1,
.nav__img-2{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .2;
}

.nav__img-1{
  width: 100px;
  top: .75rem;
  left: -2rem;
  transform: rotate(165deg);
}

.nav__img-2{
  width: 50px;
  right: -1rem;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
.
/* Show menu */
.show-menu{
  top: 0;
}

/* Change background header */
.bg-header{
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px hsla(19, 64%, 24%, .1);
}

/* Active link */


/*=============== HOME ===============*/
.home{
  position: relative;
}

.home__container{
  row-gap: 3rem;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.home__img{
  width: 300px;
  justify-self: center;
}

.home__data{
  text-align: center;
}

.home__title{
  font-size: var(--biggest-font-size);
  font-family: var(--title-font);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.home__title img{
  width: 40px;
}

.home__title div{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.home__description{
  padding: 0 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.home__leaf-1,
.home__leaf-2{
  position: absolute;
  opacity: .2;
}

.home__leaf-1{
  width: 80px;
  top: 8rem;
  left: -1rem;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.home__leaf-2{
  width: 100px;
  right: -2rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

/*=============== BUTTON ===============*/
.button{
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .5rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  transition: background .3s;
}

.button i{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.button:hover{
  background-color: var(--first-color-alt);
}

.button:hover i{
  transform: translateX(.25rem);
}

/*=============== ABOUT ===============*/
.about{
  position: relative;
}

.about__container{
  row-gap: 3rem;
}

.about__data{
  text-align: center;
}

.about__title img{
  width: 30px;
}

.about__title div{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .5rem;
}

.about__img{
  width: 300px;
  justify-self: center;
}

.about__leaf{
  width: 100px;
  opacity: .2;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1.5rem;
  bottom: 11rem;
  transform: rotate(-15deg);
}

/*=============== POPULAR ===============*/
.popular__container{
  padding-top: 4rem;
  grid-template-columns: 250px;
  justify-content: center;
  row-gap: 5.5rem;
}

.popular__card{
  position: relative;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  padding: 7rem 2rem 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 20px hsla(19, 64%, 48%, .08);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.popular__img{
  width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  top: -2.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: transform .4s;
}

.popular__name{
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  font-family: var(--title-font);
  margin-bottom: .25rem;
}

.popular__description{
  display: block;
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.popular__price{
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.popular__button{
  display: flex;
  background-color: var(--first-color);
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px hsla(19, 64%, 20%, .2);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.25rem;
  right: 1.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .3s;
}

.popular__button:hover{
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.popular__card:hover .popular__img{
  transform: translateY(-.25rem);
}

.Navbar__ToggleShow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    row-gap: 2rem;
  }


/*=============== RECENTLY ===============*/


/*=============== NEWSLETTER ===============*/


/*=============== FOOTER ===============*/


/*=============== SCROLL BAR ===============*/


/*=============== SCROLL UP ===============*/


/* Show Scroll Up*/


/*=============== BREAKPOINTS ===============*/
/* For small devices */


/* For medium devices */


/* For large devices */
```

```html
<!--==================== HEADER ====================-->
        <header class="header" id="header">
            <nav class="navcontainer">
                <a href="#" class="nav__logo">
                    <img src="assets/logo.png" alt="logo image">
                    Kaas
                </a>

                <div class="nav__menu" id="nav-menu">
                    <ul class="nav__list">
                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#home" class="nav__link">Home</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#about" class="nav__link">About us</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#popular" class="nav__link">Popular</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav__item">
                            <a href="#recently" class="nav__link">Recently</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Close button -->
                    <div id="nav-close" class="nav__close">
                        <i class="ri-close-line"></i>
                    </div>

                    <img src="assets/nav__img-1.png" alt="nav iamge" class="nav__img-1">
                    <img src="assets/nav__img-2.png" alt="nav iamge" class="nav__img-2">
                </div>

                <div class="nav__buttons">
                    <!-- Theme change button -->
                    <!-- <i class="ri-moon-line change-theme" id="theme-button"></i> -->

                    <!-- Toggle button -->
                    <div class="nav__toggle" id="nav-toggle">
                        <i class="ri-apps-2-line"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <!--==================== MAIN ====================-->
        <main class="main">
            <!--==================== HOME ====================-->
            <section class="home section" id="home">
                <div class="home__container container grid">
                    <img src="assets/home-1.png" alt="home image" class="home__img">

                    <div class="home__data">
                        <h1 class="home__title">
                            Geniet van

                            <div>
                               <img src="assets/home-2.png" alt="home image">
                               Goeie Kaas
                            </div>
                        </h1>

                        <p class="home__description">
                            Geniet van lekkere kaas met je hele familie
                            Of gewoon alleen.
                        </p>

                        <a href="#" class="button">
                            Bestel Hier <i class="ri-arrow-right-line"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <img src="assets/home-leaf-1" alt="home image" class="home__leaf-1">
                <img src="assets/home-leaf-2" alt="home image" class="home__leaf-2">
            </section>

            <!--==================== ABOUT ====================-->
            <section class="about section" id="about">
                <div class="about__container container grid">
                    <div class="about__data">
                        <span class="section__subtitle">About Us</span>
                        <h2 class="section__title about__title">
                            <div>
                                Wij Bieden U
                                <img src="assets/about-kaas-title.png" alt="about image">
                            </div>

                            Goede kaas
                        </h2>

                        <p class="about__description">
                            Kaas die van de echte kaasboer komt,
                            beter dan de kaas van de supermarkt,
                            beter dan dit kan het niet.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <img src="assets/about-kaas" alt="about image" class="about__img">
                </div>

                <img src="assets/home-leaf-1" alt="about image" class="about__leaf">
            </section>

            <!--==================== POPULAR ====================-->
            <section class="popular section" id="popular">
                <span class="secton__subtitle">De Beste Kaas</span>
                <h2 class="section__title">Populaire Kaas</h2>

                <div class="popular__container container grid">
                    <article class="popular__card">
                        <img src="assets/popular-kaas-1" alt="popular image" class="popular__img">

                        <h3 class="popular__name">Kaas 1</h3>
                        <span class="popular__description">Kaas 1</span>

                        <span class="popular__price">€5,00-</span>

                        <button class="popular__button">
                            <i class="ri-shopping-bag-line"></i>
                        </button>
                    </article>

                    <article class="popular__card">
                        <img src="assets/popular-kaas-2" alt="popular image" class="popular__img">

                        <h3 class="popular__name">Kaas 2</h3>
                        <span class="popular__description">Kaas 2</span>

                        <span class="popular__price">€5,00-</span>

                        <button class="popular__button">
                            <i class="ri-shopping-bag-line"></i>
                        </button>
                    </article>

                    <article class="popular__card">
                        <img src="assets/popular-kaas-3" alt="popular image" class="popular__img">

                        <h3 class="popular__name">Kaas 3</h3>
                        <span class="popular__description">Kaas 3</span>

                        <span class="popular__price">€5,00-</span>

                        <button class="popular__button">
                            <i class="ri-shopping-bag-line"></i>
                        </button>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!--==================== RECENTLY ====================-->
            <section class="recently section" id="recently">
                <div class="recently__container container grid">
                    <div class="recently__data">
                        <span class="section__subtitle">Recent toegevoegd</span>
                        <h2 class="section__title">
                            Kaas 1 <br>
                            Kaas 2
                        </h2>

                        <p class="recently__description">
                            Bekijk hier de nieuwe producten.
                        </p>

                        <a href="#" class="button">
                            Bestel Hier <i class="ri-arrow-right-line"></i>
                        </a>

                        <img src="assets/recently.png" alt="recently image" class="rcenlt__data-img">
                    </div>

                    <img src="assets/recently-2.png" alt="recently image" class="recently__img">
                </div>
            </section>

            <!--==================== NEWSLETTER ====================-->
            <section class="newsletter section">
                
            </section>
        </main>

        <!--==================== FOOTER ====================-->
        <footer class="footer">
            
        </footer>
```

Comment: i've attempted to use this code however i am now unable to make the nav menu show up again, it is closed however so this is already 1 step forward for me.

Comment: I also update the css code also. Please check what I did. You can check difference using this website.  https://www.diffchecker.com/

Comment: Please check my work on codepen. And let me know the result. https://codepen.io/seniordev009/pen/wvxKvQW?editors=1111